# RailsAdmin configure from multiple engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have rails app, which has muptiple engines `users`, `companies`, etc.

```
#main_app: /config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine, at: 'admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  mount Users::Engine, at: "users", as: "users"
  mount Companies::Engine, at: "companies", as: "companies"
  ...
end
```

I want to make the config `rails_admin` from main_app and also from each engine too.

```
#main_app: /config/initializers/rails_admin.rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with :cancan
  ...
end
```

In this case all work fine:

```
$ rake routes
...
Routes for RailsAdmin::Engine:
    dashboard GET         /                                      rails_admin/main#dashboard
        index GET|POST    /:model_name(.:format)                 rails_admin/main#index
          new GET|POST    /:model_name/new(.:format)             rails_admin/main#new
       export GET|POST    /:model_name/export(.:format)          rails_admin/main#export
  bulk_delete POST|DELETE /:model_name/bulk_delete(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_delete
history_index GET         /:model_name/history(.:format)         rails_admin/main#history_index
  bulk_action POST        /:model_name/bulk_action(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_action
         show GET         /:model_name/:id(.:format)             rails_admin/main#show
         edit GET|PUT     /:model_name/:id/edit(.:format)        rails_admin/main#edit
       delete GET|DELETE  /:model_name/:id/delete(.:format)      rails_admin/main#delete
 history_show GET         /:model_name/:id/history(.:format)     rails_admin/main#history_show
  show_in_app GET         /:model_name/:id/show_in_app(.:format) rails_admin/main#show_in_app
```

But when I'm trying send additional configuration from engines:

```
#users_engine: /config/initializers/rails_admin.rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.excluded_models  << "Users::Phones::ConfirmAttempt"

  config.actions do
    new do
      except ["Users::User"]
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

I have something strange in my routes, and i can't access to `rails_admin` via browser:

```
$ rake routes
...
Routes for RailsAdmin::Engine:
        new GET|POST /:model_name/new(.:format)         rails_admin/main#new
bulk_action POST     /:model_name/bulk_action(.:format) rails_admin/main#bulk_action
```

Could someone explain me, how to solve this. Or mb another way how I can be able to send configuration to `rails_admin` from each engine?

Comment: As a workaround, you could configure RailsAdmin for all engines in main app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this, because RailsAdmin.config clears the previous setup. As a workaround you can configure RailsAdmin for the all engines in main app.

Answer (score 1):

`config.actions` in Rails Admin overrides all default actions. You have to define them all again in the configuration like this:

```
users_engine: /config/initializers/rails_admin.rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

  config.actions do
    # root actions
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    # collection actions 
    index                         # mandatory
    new do
      except ["Users::User"]
    end
    export
    history_index
    bulk_delete
    # member actions
    show
    edit
    delete
    history_show
    show_in_app
  end
  ...
end
```

However this will also override any configuration you would have in your main app or other engines.

Comment: I'm already undestand this. You answer is not the one that I need. I need workaround of my problem.